# Toric Fano 4-folds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In the work of Batyrev on the classification of toric Fano 4-folds the author gives a list of all Toric Fano 4-folds. What does it mean for example to blow up two surfaces $\mathbb{P}^2$ on something? Is it just two disjoint projective planes? Or the projective planes intersect transversally? Is the strict or proper transform again $\mathbb{P}^2$ in the case of transversal intersection?

Comment: Try to explain your question more clearly!

Comment: In the work of Batyrev you can find the following toric Fano 4-fold in his list: $X=\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}(1,0)\oplus\mathcal{O}(0,1))$; now blow up three surfaces $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ on $X$. And my problem is what does that exactelly mean? Does this mean three times or does this mean that you blow up on time and then all three surfaces together?

Comment: This $X \to \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ that you have has three sections (each isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$), which are fixed under the torus action, may be you mean blowing up along each of these three sub varieties.

Comment: No, these are three different sections of this fibration. Each fiber which is $\mathbb{P}^2$, has three distinguished points which lie on one of these sections.  Please think a bit!